# 2003 Honda CR-V passenger window doesn’t work using either switch. Fuse for pass. window blows every time I use the master switch

Tags: honda, power-windows, crv, switches

This is a 2003 Honda CR-V EX.  The passenger window doesn’t go up or down. Neither switch works. The fuse for the pass. window blows every time I try the master switch, even when I disconnect the Pass. window motor from the circuit. No power seems to make it to the passenger window.  All other windows work just fine, using either the master switch or the local window switch.  Dead short in the wiring?  Dead short in the master switch?  I can’t find a wiring diagram of the power window circuit. not sure if the window motor works as I am hesitant to power up a circuit when I am not sure which wire in the circuit is the motor wire.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you also considered the window motor might be dead?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need a diagram to start with. Open the drivers door and between the door and chassis you'll find a boot that contains all the wiring that goes from the door to the modules. Gain access to the wires inside and inspect all wires. You might very well find some damaged wires that need repaired. This is a common place for wire damage due to opening and closing the door so many times. Don't forget to unhook the battery before doing this.

Comment: Before you disconnect the power, if you have the original head unit in the vehicle, make sure you have the security code for it prior to unhooking your battery, or you might have issues getting it reactivated without taking it to the dealer.

Comment: I checked out the wiring between the door and the chassis, and OMG, the wiring is wrapped and armored in plastic. I would have to take the door off to access the wiring at that point. There must be a connector in there somewhere. I found a wiring diagram, but the wiring on the passenger seems to be dead, no power, no ground. Has to be wiring connected…sigh…